# What types of "office:value-type" and "calcext:value-type" attributes exist in LibreOffice Calc "table:table-cell" tag?

Tags: xml, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm building LibreOffice Calc files with python code, and I want to find all types of "office:value-type" and "calcext:value-type" attributes that I can use (e.g. "string", "float", "int" - I'm not sure that's all of them). Thanks!

P.S. please provide documentation topic link, I can't seem to find any proper related material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a discussion at http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/cd05/OpenDocument-v1.2-cd05-part1.html#a_19_387_office_value-type.  This is for ODF 1.2, which is the [current version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument#Future).

The attributes listed are: `boolean, currency, date, float, percentage, string, time` and "void" (that is, no attribute).  You also mentioned `int` although it is not in the list.

The link does not mention `calcext:value-type`.  However Google shows examples of this attribute using `float, string, date, currency`, so it seeems to be similar or identical to the `office:value-type` list.

Comment: The difference is that calcext:value-type allows error. office:value-type does not allow to differentiate between error cells and cells that just contain a string that looks like an error. Sadly ODF does not allow to add new values to existing attributes.